# Android Studio errors after adding external library

Tags: java, android, java-8, android-build

I've got the following problem:

I'm programming an app which is using Google Maps and I wanted to add this external lib

https://github.com/route360/r360-java

I wanted to add the lib as .jar file into Android Studio, so I compiled it with Maven using Java 8 (Compiling with Java 7 didn't work).

After adding the .jar as lib and adding it to the dependencies and running the app I get the following error messages:

```
Error:PARSE ERROR:
Error:unsupported class file version 52.0
Error:...while parsing net/motionintelligence/client/Constants.class
Error:1 error; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

After some research in SO I found out that this may be the result of a wrong Java version I'm using so I installed Java 7, changed the Android Studio JDK to Java 7 and tried to run the app. The result is the following:

```
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I'm tried switching between the Android API's but no solution from SO worked out for me.

At the moment im using API 23 Android 6.0.

Here my build.gradle file of the submodule:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jule.bachelorapp"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    dexOptions {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile files('libs/r360-java-client-0.0.1.jar')
}
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of those errors ? I really need to use that library so help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: ` Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` . This comes because the class files are not compatible with your JRE . You need J2SE 8 to avoid this error. AFter reverting back to 8, enable multidex in your gradle. Something like `defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}` .

Answer (score 1):

Android does not provide the `javax.ws.rs` package currently used for networking in the r360-java library so you won't be able to use this library.

A list of Android supported Java packages is available [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

Comment: Bad news for me but thanks for the answer. I spent hours trying to solve that problem but now at least I know what caused that. 

Thanks !

Comment: Where is the javax.ws.rs package getting used ?

Comment: If you have a look at the `net.motionintelligence.client.api.request` package e.g. https://github.com/route360/r360-java/blob/master/src/main/java/net/motionintelligence/client/api/request/PolygonRequest.java - you will see references and the usage of `javax.ws.rs.client.Client`

Comment: See more info. regarding restrictions on using java libraries on Android: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html#androidjarfile_restrictions